# If $h_m \to h$ in $C([0,T])$, then the characteristic function $\chi_{A_{h_m}} \to \chi_{A_{h}}$ in $L^p$.

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I was reading a lemma in a article and there is some point in the proof I don't understand:

Let $A\subset \mathbb R^2$ be a bounded set. We set
$$\tilde A = A - A = \{x - y~|~x, y \in A\}.$$
Now let us consider $h_m, h \in C([0,T], \mathbb R^2)$ with $(h_m)_{m \in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence such that $h_m \to h$ strongly and we set
$$A_{h_m(t)} = A + h_m(t) \quad \text{and} \quad A_{h(t)} = A + h(t).$$
From these we would like to show that $\chi_{\tilde A \backslash A_{h_m(t)}} \to \chi_{\tilde A \backslash A_{h(t)}}$ strongly in $L^p(]0,T[ \times \tilde A)$ for all $p \in [1, \infty)$, where $\chi_\Omega$ stands for the characteristic function of the set $\Omega$. Therefore we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^T \int_{\tilde A} |\chi_{\tilde A \backslash A_{h_m(t)}} - \chi_{\tilde A \backslash A_{h(t)}}|^p &= \int_0^T \mu( A_{h(t)} \backslash A_{h_m(t)}) +  \int_0^T \mu( A_{h_m(t)} \backslash A_{h(t)}) \\
&\le C \int_0^T |h(t) - h_m(t)|
\end{align}
and this concludes the lemma. However, I really don't see how get the inequality. The first equality is intuitive if you draw a picture but I wasn't able to bound the sum, I tried many things but nothing I've done has worked.. Any idea ?

Comment: Yes indeed, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the crucial inequality is not true. Let us define the set
$$
A = \bigcup_{n = 0}^\infty
\bigg[
(2^{-n},2^{-n-1}) \times \Big\{
\bigcup_{m = 1}^{2^n}
( (m-1)2^{-n}, (m-1)2^{-n} + 2^{-n-1})
\Big\}
\bigg].
$$
A picture is worth more than thousand symbols:
[image: fractal set]

Let $A_t := A + t \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, $f(t) = \mu( A_t \setminus A)$. Then, $f(t) \le C t$ does not hold.
Indeed, one can check that
$$f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \operatorname{saw}(t,n) \qquad\forall t \in (0,1/2),$$
where $\operatorname{saw}(\cdot,n)$
is a triangle wave with amplitude $2^{-n-1}$ and period $2^{-n}$.

Here is a nice picture of $t \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^{20}\operatorname{saw}(t,n)$:
[image: fractal function]

Thus,
$$
f(2^{-n}) = \frac{n}{2} 2^{-n}$$
for $n \ge 0$.

With this it should be possible to get a contradiction to the mentioned lemma by considering constant functions $h_m$ and $h$.

Comment: Why the downvote?